# Vertica different calculations than in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, vertica

I have one query:

```
SELECT CAST(((stats.ts_spawn - 1427835600) / 86400) * 86400 + 
1427835600 AS INTEGER) AS anon_1 FROM stats WHERE stats.ts_spawn > 
1427835600 AND stats.ts_spawn < 1428440399 GROUP BY anon_1 order by anon_1;
```

I'm expecting to get start of the each day in a week.

Result in Postgresql:

```
1427835600
1427922000
1428008400
1428094800
1428181200
1428267600
1428354000
```

Vertica returns start of each hour of each day of the week:

```
1427839200
1427842800
1427846400
1427850000
... and so on, total 167 records(24 * 7 - 1)
```

I have no idea how to modify this query.

Comment: Let me guess: difference in timezones (the difference seems to be 3600)? BTW: maybe you could use the date functions date_trunc() date_part() instead?

Comment: Seems like storing in `timestamp` would save you a lot of work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is obviously resulting in a float not an integer in division. In [Vertica documents](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.0.x/HP_Vertica_6.0.2_Release_Notes.pdf) we can read this:

> the Vertica 6 release introduced a behavior change when dividing integers using the / operator

If you want the query to behave the same on both systems either change the configuration option as mentioned in that doc or use the `Floor()` function on the result of division.